# Kernel selection for unknown data in Gaussian process regression

Tags: normal-distribution, gaussian-process

I'm new to Gaussian process regression (GPR). My recent work is to model some longitudinal data with GPR.

I have learnt so far that GPR was highly flexible non-parametric method and the kernel determined the behaviour of GPR model. However, in longitudinal data modelling sometimes with the entry of new observations the data behaviour could change dramatically. For example, let $x_t$ denote the observation of longitudinal random variable $x$ at time $t$:

$x_0 = 1.2, x_1 = 2.1, x_2 = 3.9, x_3 = 2.2, x_4 = 0.9$

If an observer only makes observation from $t = 0$ to $t = 2$, they might suggest using a non-periodic kernel. An observer who observes up until $t=4$ will probably conclude using a periodic kernel. A careless observer who only observes $x_1$ and $x_3$ might even say using a stationary kernel as the data did not change much at all.

Currently, I'm thinking of using a composite kernel of different kernels for this problem, but it would be greatly appreciated if someone could provide ideas on some more brillant solutions.

Thanks in advance!

P.S.: Currently I mainly use GPyTorch in Python, but other tools are appreciated as well.

Comment: Can you clarify what "longitudinal data" mean to you? It sounds like you have equally spaced observations over time, with a single value corresponding to each observation (i.e. what some people might call a discrete univariate time series problem)?

Comment: It might help to edit in a specific question, which I think is something like "How do I choose a kernel?"

Comment: Dear John, I mean observations made irregularly over time (or we do not force them to be equally spaced over time). There might be missing observations as well. The length between each pair observation and whether an observation is missing or not is beyond one's control and is something I hope the model to accommodate for.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. (FYI: commenters are not notified of your replies unless you "at them", e.g. @JohnMadden). Two things: 1) Yes, if you're worried about the *nature* of the stochastic process changing wrt time, you will need to employ some sophisticated procedure like a composition of kernels, or may I recommend a deepGP. but 2) GPs with a "standard" kernel are quite flexible, and we would want to have a fair number of data if we were going to be juggling multiple kernels around. My advice would be to try a simple kernel first and convince yourself that it's insufficient before trying 1).

Comment: Thanks for all replies and suggestions!